# Apply() for a function with two parameters to apply over

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a function which have two parameters needed to be cycled. As far as I know, `apply()` only can apply over one array parameter with a dimension indicator. I wonder is there anyway to apply over two array parameters? Here is an example:

```
matrix_a <- matrix(1:6,3,2)
matrix_b <- matrix(2:7,3,2)


fun1 <- function(par1,par2){
   mean(par1+par2) #true function are more complex than this
}

result <- numeric(nrow(matrix_a))

#this for loop give me exactly what I want, however, is there any sophistical way to do this? Like use a apply() function
for(i in 1:nrow(matrix_a)){
  result[i] <- fun1(matrix_a[i,], matrix_b[i,])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy convert the matrices to transposed data frames, there are a number of nice options. So start with the following:

```
matrix_a <- matrix(1:6,3,2)
matrix_b <- matrix(2:7,3,2)

df_a <- data.frame(t(matrix_a))
df_b <- data.frame(t(matrix_b))
```

Note that use of `t()` to transpose is because your example involves rowwise operations. Your "more complex" function may not need this.

Then, some options are base `mapply()`, or few `map*` functions from the purrr package. Examples...

Using base `mapply()`, which accepts a function and multiple inputs to iterate over:

```
mapply(function(i, j) mean(i + j), df_a, df_b)
#> X1 X2 X3 
#>  6  8 10
```

Using purrr map2, which takes two inputs to iterate over:

```
library(purrr)
map2(df_a, df_b, ~ mean(.x + .y))      # returns list
#> $X1
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $X2
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> $X3
#> [1] 10

map2_dbl(df_a, df_b, ~ mean(.x + .y))  # returns numeric vector
#> X1 X2 X3 
#>  6  8 10
```

Using purrr `pmap()` which takes a list of multiple inputs. Here I'll add a third data frame (b again) to demonstrate a more general example:

```
pmap_dbl(list(df_a, df_b, df_b), ~ mean(sum(.)))
#> X1 X2 X3 
#>  7  9 11
```

Answer (score 1):

One method

```
sapply(1:nrow(matrix_a), function(i) fun1(matrix_a[i,], matrix_b[i,]))
```